# Value annotations around Plotly sunburst diagram

Tags: plotly, sunburst-diagram

In this example of a Plotly sunburst plot taken from [the docs](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/#sunburst-of-a-rectangular-dataframe-with-plotlyexpress), how can I display the values as text outside the outer-most level? I would like to have an annotation for each segment showing the value determining its radial width.

[My actual plots](https://github.com/janosh/ml-matrics/tree/938d92b8d1ef98a06f45cb27df7c33ec7a3940a4#sunburst) have several hundred segments in the outer-most layer so any solution should be fully automatic and require no hard-coded values.

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['day', 'time', 'sex'], values='total_bill')
fig.show()
```

[image: plotly sunburst]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Plotly sunburst charts have any built-in annotations, so you'll need to add the annotations manually.

In your case, I think using `go.Scatter()` with the argument `mode='text'` will you allow to place the annotations over the sunburst chart. This method has the advantage of placing the sunburst chart over whatever coordinates are most convenient.

For example, if you set the range of the x- and y- axes to `[-1,1]` this will ensure that the sunburst chart is centered at (0,0) with a radius of approximately 1 (EDIT: as suggested by @Rene, if you fix the width and height of the figure, you can guarantee that the sunburst chart is circular and that the aspect ratio of the browser window won't change the [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)) of the sunburst chart). You may also want some padding on these ranges to ensure that the text isn't cut off if it's near the upper or lower end of the range.

Then you can use polar coordinates to determine the x and y coordinates based on r and theta. So if you want to place the annotation `"1227"` at 45 degrees, then set `x=r*cos(45˚)` and `y=r*sin(45˚).` And repeat this process with all of the annotations you want to place down.

UPDATE: although Plotly renders the sunburst chart with the categories in the correct order, it doesn't appear that this information is stored in an accessible object, which leaves us with the task of determining the order of the categories and their respective angles ourselves.

For a Plotly sunburst chart, the sum of the categories (`day`, `time`, and `sex`) within its parent category determines the order in which they are placed on the chart starting from 0 degrees. For example, the sum of `total_tips` for category `day` is largest for `Sat` followed by `Sun, Thur, Fri`, and this is the order these categories and their values are placed on the chart. And for a child category within a parent category, the same pattern applies: for example, the sum of `total_tips` for `Sat/Dinner/Male` is larger than `Sat/Dinner/Female` so the value corresponding to Sat/Dinner/Male is placed before Sat/Dinner/Female.

We can reproduce this ordering using a combination of `groupby` and `sort_values`:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from math import sin,cos,pi

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['day', 'time', 'sex'], values='total_bill', width=600, height=600)

totals_groupby =  df.groupby(['day', 'time', 'sex']).sum()
totals_groupby["day_sum"] = df.groupby(['day', 'time', 'sex']).total_bill.sum().groupby(level='day').transform('sum')
totals_groupby["day_time_sum"] = df.groupby(['day', 'time', 'sex']).total_bill.sum().groupby(level=['day','time']).transform('sum')
totals_groupby["day_time_sex_sum"] = df.groupby(['day', 'time', 'sex']).total_bill.sum().groupby(level=['day','time','sex']).transform('sum')
totals_groupby = totals_groupby.sort_values(by=["day_sum","day_time_sum","day_time_sex_sum"], ascending=[0,0,0])
```

---

Below is the `totals_groupby` DataFrame where we have reproduced the same category orders as the Plotly express sunburst chart:

```
>>> totals_groupby
                    total_bill     tip  size  day_sum  day_time_sum  day_time_sex_sum
day  time   sex                                                                      
Sat  Dinner Male       1227.35  181.95   156  1778.40       1778.40           1227.35
            Female      551.05   78.45    63  1778.40       1778.40            551.05
Sun  Dinner Male       1269.46  186.78   163  1627.16       1627.16           1269.46
            Female      357.70   60.61    53  1627.16       1627.16            357.70
Thur Lunch  Male        561.44   89.41    73  1096.33       1077.55            561.44
            Female      516.11   79.42    77  1096.33       1077.55            516.11
     Dinner Female       18.78    3.00     2  1096.33         18.78             18.78
Fri  Dinner Male        164.41   21.23    16   325.88        235.96            164.41
            Female       71.55   14.05    10   325.88        235.96             71.55
     Lunch  Female       55.76   10.98     9   325.88         89.92             55.76
            Male         34.16    5.70     5   325.88         89.92             34.16
```

The annotations we want are the values in the `total_bill` column of `totals_groupby` and are in the order corresponding to the plotly.express sunburst figure.

Then we can calculate the angles *subtended* by each category by dividing the `total_bill` column by the grand total of total_bill and multiply by 360 for angles in degrees. Note that this isn't the final angle where we want to place the annotations: to get that, we need to take a rolling mean of these angles starting from 0.

```
annotations = [format(v,".0f") for v in totals_groupby.total_bill.values]

## calculate the angle subtended by each category
sum_total_bill = df.total_bill.sum()
delta_angles = 360*totals_groupby["total_bill"] / sum_total_bill

## calculate cumulative sum starting from 0, then take a rolling mean 
## to get the angle where the annotations should go
angles_in_degrees = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data=[0]),delta_angles]).cumsum().rolling(window=2).mean().dropna().values
```

---

```
>>> annotations
['1227', '551', '1269', '358', '561', '516', '19', '164', '72', '56', '34']
>>> list(angles_in_degrees[:,0])
[45.76087924652581, 112.06726915325291, 179.94370071482274, 240.6112138730718, 274.8807006133266, 315.0563924959142, 334.9993889518348, 341.82949891979104, 350.6271011253642, 355.3737646988153, 358.726368488971]
```

Now we can place all of this information on the sunburst chart using a helper function to convert the angle to x,y coordinates.

```
def get_xy_coordinates(angles_in_degrees, r=1):
    return [r*cos(angle*pi/180) for angle in angles_in_degrees], [r*sin(angle*pi/180) for angle in angles_in_degrees]

x_coordinates, y_coordinates = get_xy_coordinates(angles_in_degrees, r=1.13)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=x_coordinates,
    y=y_coordinates,
    mode="text",
    text=annotations,
    hoverinfo="skip",
    textfont=dict(size=14)
))

padding = 0.20
fig.update_layout(
    width=600, 
    height=600,
    xaxis=dict(
        range=[-1 - padding, 1 + padding], 
        showticklabels=False
    ), 
    yaxis=dict(
        range=[-1 - padding, 1 + padding],
        showticklabels=False
    ),
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm writing a plotting function so I don't have the luxury of hard-coding any angles or sort orders. Hoping there will be another more automated approach. But thanks for showing all the parts that go into a solution!

Comment: Yeah I completely understand not wanting to hardcode any part of the solution. In that case, you'll need to dig deeper into how plotly constructs the sunburst chart under the hood. Perhaps there's a formula you can use to determine the angles or sort order based on the hierarchy of the parents, ids, and relative values - if I think of anything, I'll update my answer

Comment: I have updated my answer! the category orders and angles can be determined from the data without being hardcoded... hopefully this is closer to what you are looking for

Comment: Cool! Wouldn't it be easier to use the [`plotly.graph_objects.Scatterpolar`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatterpolar) trace type instead of converting back to Cartesian coords?

Comment: Oh that's an excellent point - that could definitely make things easier

Comment: I made some modifications to make reuse easy

https://gist.github.com/rcsmit/0924bff91bc406ed8be55520b50d1748

Comment: It is making an elipse. imgur.com/a/xGCiC0a
To make it a circle use  fig = px.sunburst(df, path=[aaa, bbb, ccc], values=ddd, width=600, height=600, )

Comment: That's a good catch, thanks @Rene – i'll update my answer later when i have a moment

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a perfect answer to this question specifically, but a similar outcome can be reached by editing the starburst figure's data field.

```
df = px.data.tips()
p = px.sunburst(df, path=['day', 'time', 'sex'], values='total_bill')
p.update_layout(
    margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=0, b=0),
)
p.data[0].labels=np.array(list(zip(p.data[0].labels, p.data[0].values)))
p.show(renderer='svg')
```

Certainly, this doesn't position the labels outside the outer ring, but it is fully automatic, keeps consistent fonts and styling, and also labels the inner partitions by default. If value labels must be restricted to the outer ring, the zip can be modified.

unfortunately it appears the text positioning cannot work with carriage returns in strings. At least, I ran into unexpected behavior when using `"\n".join` in various ways.

Comment: Thanks @panos. Here's what the output looks like. Can't add it to the answer due to full edit queue. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30958850/200197101-da75bc4a-b80d-4a40-a935-fe2b66551c09.svg